# alfresco 5 and solr4 in different linux boxes

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

we are planning to upgrade from alfresco 4.2 to alfresco 5.0.Currently in prod env,Alfresco 4.2 and solr4 are in different boxes i.e tomcat servers.I dont know how they have deployed these instances at that time.

Now how to install alfresco 5.0 and solr4 in different boxes?Do we need to use same installer file for alfresco 5 & solr4 as well and install it in different boxes?

When we installed in local windows,both alfresco and solr4 comes in the same tomcat instance.but in linux , how to install it in different boxes?

Comment: Don't use the installer, and [deploy it by hand](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/solr4-install-config.html)? Likely the safest way anyway for a production system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/solr4-install-config.html) is a good resource for this.

You can run the installer on your Alfresco server and then run it again on the Solr server. On the Alfresco server, delete the solr4 WAR. And on the Solr server, delete everything but the Solr4 WAR.

In alf_data, there is a keystore directory that needs to be identical on both servers.

You'll need to edit alfresco-global.properties on the Alfresco box to point to the Solr host.

And, you'll need to edit the alfresco-global.properties on the Solr box to point to the solr indices.

Between the docs and these tips you should be able to figure it out.